# Asset file/folder permissions issue

Tags: assets, permissions, hosting

Craft seems to create asset files and folders with permissions 775 and 664. My host has restrictions in place to not serve folders/files with these permissions.

Where can I change this?

Answer (score 4):

Of course as soon as I post this, I find the answer.

> /app/etc/config/defaults/general.php
>
> 'defaultFilePermissions' => 0664,
>
> 'defaultFolderPermissions' => 0775,

The default settings are there, I just need to add them to my own config.